# Texture is distorted even when the stretch is shown completly blue

Tags: texturing, uv

Like the title is telling some areas of the texture is distorted even when the displayed stretch of the area is completly blue. You can see the distortion where I drawn the question mark in the Image below. Does anyone know a way to fix it?

Thanks for reading.

[image: Distorted Texture]

---

The face is a quad. I pulled the vertices a little forward in the following image to demonstrate this:

[image]

Comment: I can't quite tell - what type of face is that? It looks like a quad on the UV map but it's hard to tell whether it's not an ngon in the right pane.

Comment: Hi Kibo, instead of posting an answer please [edit] the question.  This helps us keep everything organized and makes search results more accurate.  Thanks for your contribution!